# how can i rewrite this code without using arrays?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    int a[x][x];
    int i, j, low = 0, top = x - 1, n = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < x / 2; i++, low++, top--)
    {
        for (j = low; j <= top; j++, n++)
            a[i][j] = n;
        for (j = low + 1; j <= top; j++, n++)
            a[j][top] = n;
        for (j = top - 1; j >= low; j--, n++)
            a[top][j] = n;
        for (j = top - 1; j > low; j--, n++)
            a[j][low] = n;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

i want to write a number pattern and this is the code but i wanted to write it without arrays.how can i rewrite this without using any arrays?
and of course x can be both even and odd.
thanks for ur help![image: ![example for output]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rxdS.png)

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Gotta admit, it's one of a kind weird for loop nesting I have seen in recent times. Are you trying to obfuscate your code?

Comment: Please show the (desired) output.

Comment: *"but i wanted to write it without arrays"* - But why?

Comment: Just wondering: Who's upvoting this?

Comment: @SouravGhosh some people who hate arrays . . . and clear code :(

Comment: Is it supposed to work for odd inputs or only for even?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya In that case, they should not be getting "a-raise". :P

Comment: @yunnosch it should work for both odd and even input.

Comment: This question boils down to "please write my code for me", and they are usually poory received here (down votes etc). It would be good to explain what you have tried, and just how you are stumped with your problem.

Comment: Try 5 and explain the largest visible number please.

Comment: Also, example output, or specification of what the code is supposed to do, would be essential. Now you ask everybody to decipher what your code does by themselves, and test it, and generally very few here want to do this, unless problem is very interesting to them.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just post the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int get(int x, int y, int lt, int n)
{
    if(x == 0)
        return lt+y;
    else if(y == 0)
        return lt+4*(n-1)-x;
    else if(y == n-1)
        return lt+n+x-1;
    else if(x == n-1)
        return lt+3*(n-1)-y;
    else
        return get(x-1, y-1, lt+4*(n-1), n-2);
}
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            printf("%2d ", get(i, j, 1, n));
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: input:6                                                                                                                                     result:                                                                                                                                   
  1   2   3   4   5   6

  20  21  22  23  24   7

  19  32  33  34  25   8

  18  31  36  35  26   9

  17  30  29  28  27  10

  16  15  14  13  12  11

Answer (score 0):

I must agree that this code is incredible difficult for me to understand. I have no clue what is happening here. But I will try to answer it irrespective of the logic/pattern.

So you have a bunch of loops that fill in an array and then another loop that prints it in order. But you don't want to use arrays.

So the value should be calculated **when** it is to be printed. Let us try it this way -

First I will move your calculating code to a separate function for sake for clarity -

```
int value_at(int I, int J, int x) {
    int i, j, low = 0, top = x - 1, n = 1;
    int a = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x / 2; i++, low++, top--) {
        for (j = low; j <= top; j++, n++)
            if ( i == I && j == J)
                a = n;
        for (j = low + 1; j <= top; j++, n++)
            if ( I == j && J == top)
                a = n;
        for (j = top - 1; j >= low; j--, n++)
            if ( top == I && j == J)
                a = n
        for (j = top - 1; j > low; j--, n++)
            if (j == I && low == J)
                a = n;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Now this function calculates the value of `a` for any `i` or `j`

Now we can just print the values in a loop -

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{

    for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", value_at(i, j, x));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried figuring out the logic. It was just not possible. So I decided to give a bad answer to a bad question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This must do the task :

```
int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a<b ? a:b;
}

void printSpiral(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            int x;

            x = min(min(i, j), min(n-1-i, n-1-j));

            // For upper right half
            if (i <= j)
                printf("%d ", ((n*n) - ((n-2*x)*(n-2*x) - (i-x)
                    - (j-x)))+1);

            // for lower left half
            else
                printf("%d ", ((n*n) - ((n-2*x-2)*(n-2*x-2) + (i-x)
                    + (j-x)))+1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Just call `printSpiral()` and pass your `x` as argument